# Python changing variable values declared in __init__

Tags: class, python-3.x

I hesitate to ask this question, but my head cannot seem to get around the use of `class`, `__init__()`, and `str`. Hoping that someone will be patient enough to answer what is probably a very dumb question.
I have written the following to test my understanding ( = 0)"

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.__var1 = var1
        self.__var2 = var2
    def change_var1(self):
        self.__var1
        self.__var1 =2*self.__var1
        return self.__var1, self.__var2
    def change_var2(self):
        self.__var2
        self.__var2 = self.__var2*2
        return self.__var1, self.__var2
    def __repr__(self):
        return "var1 is {}, and var 2 = {}".format(self.__var1, self.__var2)

t = Test(4,"Bye")
print(t.change_var1 )  
print(t.change_var2)
```

I cannot get the variables declared in **init** to be changed by the subsequent functions. I assume that I have used class, **init**, str__ incorrectly.
The response to running what I have above is:

```
<bound method Test.change_var1 of var1 is 4, and var 2 = Bye>
<bound method Test.change_var2 of var1 is 4, and var 2 = Bye>
```

Grateful for any help, push to a site that will get through the brick wall of my mind!!

Comment: Just a tip: The first line underneath each `change_var()` function is unnecessary. Only the line assigning the variable is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `print(t.change_var1)`, you are not *calling* the `change_var1 function`, you are merely *referencing* it. It is not getting called, so it doesn't actually do anything.

To call it you need to append parentheses:

```
print(t.change_var1())
print(t.change_var2())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I still have a problem, though. If I do as you say print(t.change_var1()) and print(t.change_var2()) and then add print(t) I get back my str "var1 is 8, and var 2 = ByeBye". But if I only use print(t) I get back "var1 is 4, and var 2 = Bye". Could you explain why calling the class method, does not change  variables? If I try print(t()), it gives me TypeError: 'Test' object is not callable. I am very dense!!!

Comment: you can only get ByeBye if you call `t.change_var2()` first. calling `print(t)` without changing the variable will only give you Bye. When you say "calling the class method" do you mean `t = Test(4,"Bye")` ? That will only call `__init__()`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess the question is "What am I doing wrong?". You have the concepts correct, but I believe a review of the [Python syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) is in order.

If you look at the two examples there, you will see that one ***calls*** the function called `fib` using parenthesis, e.g. `>>>fib(1000)`, but can reference the function itself by simply entering `>>>fib`. Try removing the `print()` surrounding those last two lines and you'll  get the same result. Add parenthesis and you'll be golden.

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Still a tad confused as you will see from my comment to @salparadise