# python basic class question, where am i going wrong

Tags: python, class, python-2.x

I'm slowly trying to get my head around classes. I have a few working examples which i kinda understand but can someone please explain to me why this doesn’t work?

```
class python:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name

  def changename(self,newname):
    self.name=newname

abc=python('python')

print abc.name

abc.changename = 'anaconda'

print abc.name
```

All I’m trying to do here is change the value of `abc.name` at some point later in the code (it doesn’t need to be name if that’s a special word, but I did try name2, etc, same results...)

If I do `print abc.changename` then I get the output anaconda but that’s not really what i wanted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also...Is it possible to do something like that at a later point in the life cycle of the code?

```
def newstuff(self, value1, value2):
  self.newvalue1 = value1
  self.newvalue2 = value2
```

So that I would have access to 2 new ‘things’ `abc.newvalue1` and `abc.newvalue2`.

Does that make sense??

Sorry for the ‘things; I’m still trying to grasp which is an attribute, object, method, item, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python changing variable values declared in \_\_init\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894295/python-changing-variable-values-declared-in-init)

Comment: `abc.changename` is a method. Why are you assigning a string to it: `abc.changename = 'anaconda'`? Also, while you're just starting learning Python, switch to Python 3.x as Python 2 will stop receiving updates in 2020

Comment: Change abc.changename = 'anaconda' to abc.changename('anaconda'). changename is a function, not a variable, and has to be treated accordingly. :)

Comment: Not just *in* 2020; support ends once 2020 begins. That's in less than 19 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
abc.changename = 'anaconda'
```

to this:

```
abc.changename('anaconda')
```

You defined the method `changename` to access your member `name`. Then, in the first line you try to access the member directly without using the method.

In the second case, yes it would work:

```
def newstuff(self, value1, value2):
    self.name1 = value1
    self.name2 = value2
```

But you would have to add 1 member to your class, and should then access the method like this:

```
class python:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.name1 = value1
        self.name2 = value2


abc=python('python1', 'python2')
abc.newstuff('snake', 'anaconda')
```

Answer (score 1):

`abc.changename` is a method. To use it, write it with the parenthesis and the value into them.
`abc.changename('anaconda')`
Hope it'll help you

Answer (score 1):

You declared `abc.changename` as a function. Invoke it by using `abc.changename("Sandman112")`

What you did is you assigned a string to the member variable `abc.changename` instead of the class method you defined eariler.